# Html.BeginForm and adding properties

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How would I go about adding `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to a form that is generated by using `<% Html.BeginForm(); %>`?

Answer (score 259, accepted):

As part of htmlAttributes,e.g.

```
Html.BeginForm(
    action, controller, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype="multipart/form-data"})
```

Or you can pass `null` for action and controller to get the same default target as for BeginForm() without any parameters:

```
Html.BeginForm(
    null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype="multipart/form-data"})
```

Comment: hi, how do i specify enctype as Shift-JIS which is japanese encoding format?

Comment: I always prefer to specify the action / controller, because the url can be manipulated depending on what you page do, so letting action / controller on null may cause unexpected behaviors.

Answer (score 19):

You can also use the following syntax for the strongly typed version:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm<SomeController>(x=> x.SomeAction(), 
          FormMethod.Post, 
          new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })) 
   { %>
```

Comment: Can't do this in the current version (RC1).

Comment: Which is a massive bummer :( So how can we do this? do we need another dll? MVC futures or something?

Comment: Yes, indeed...I believe all of the strongly typed (expression-based) methods are in the futures assembly (http://aspnet.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=24471).

Comment: @Jason, dp: Using Nick's extension method, it would be possible to provide that kind of signature, too. Still including futures is certainly a better approach.

Answer (score 13):

I know this is old but you could create a custom extension if you needed to create that form over and over:

```
public static MvcForm BeginMultipartForm(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper)
{
    return htmlHelper.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, 
     new Dictionary<string, object>() { { "enctype", "multipart/form-data" } });
}
```

Usage then just becomes

```
<% using(Html.BeginMultipartForm()) { %>
```